# nest queries and pass their results as alias to SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, I'm running two queries that returns me the X amount of items per month through a year.

the 1st query gives me the following result

[image: 1st query]

the 'no column name' would be the months, so I have no data in august, november and december.

The second query, gives me the following

[image: 2nd query]

only August and Setpember has data.

What I'm trying to figure out is how can I sum both tables to get the 100% value, then define each % (corretivas x preventivas).
In my research, I assume I have to nest the queries, but I just can't reach the logic to get me near the wanted result.

this is my queries so far

```
select month(workOrderDate), COUNT(*) as preventivas from WorkOrder WHERE
workOrderDescription = 'preventiva'
AND YEAR(workOrderDate) = 2018
AND lastUpdateData IS NOT NULL
AND WorkType = '02'
group BY MONTH(workOrderDate)
ORDER BY MONTH(workOrderDate)

select MONTH(workOrderDate), COUNT(*) AS corretivas from WorkOrder WHERE
YEAR(workOrderDate) = 2018
AND workOrderDescription = 'CORRETIVA' 
AND lastUpdateData IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY MONTH(workOrderDate)
ORDER BY MONTH(workOrderDate)
```

The expected result would be

[image: expected result]
and so on

Would anybody helpe me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You want conditional aggregation  :

```
SELECT MONTH(wo.workOrderDate), COUNT(*) AS total,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN wo.WorkType = '02' AND wo.orkOrderDescription = 'preventiva' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*)) * 100 AS preventiva,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN wo.orkOrderDescription = 'CORRETIVA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*)) * 100 AS CORRETIVA
FROM WorkOrder wo
WHERE YEAR(wo.workOrderDate) = 2018 AND wo.lastUpdateData IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY MONTH(wo.workOrderDate);
```

Comment: `SELECT MONTH(workOrderDate) AS MES,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN WorkType = '02' AND workOrderDescription = 'preventiva' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)) AS preventiva,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN workOrderDescription = 'CORRETIVA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS corretivas
FROM WorkOrder 
WHERE YEAR(workOrderDate) = 2018 AND lastUpdateData IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY MONTH(workOrderDate);`

now I get almost everything in the same table, thing here is (corretiva + preventiva) = 100% wich is `total`, and the representig percent of each preventiva and corretiva shoul be calculated based on the `total`